# Show menu onclick on multiple posts with same classes

Tags: javascript, html

So I made a posting system with PHP and it's finally working, though, I have a problem. I coded a javascript that opens the post menu, but it won't open at all. If I were to use the `getElementById` function, only the first post will be selected so the other posts' menu won't open, so I tried using the `getElementsByClassName`, but now the menu won't open in any posts.

Here is my code:

javascript

```
let postMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("post-Menu");
let morebtn = document.getElementsByClassName("morebtn");

morebtn.onclick = function() {
    postMenu.classList.toggle("postmenShow");
}
```

html

```
<div class="postmenu">
    <div class="morebtn">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1hdv0qi">
            <g>
                <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="post-Menu">
        <a href="">
            <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-pen"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id="to-open"` ... I highly suspect you have duplicated IDs in your document.

Comment: PS. Don't use inline on*  handlers

Comment: I tried removing that earlier and nothing changed at all

Comment: im replying to Roko C. Buljan by the way, but thanks for that

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return an array like nodelist so `morebtn.onclick` is not correct, neither is `postMenu.classList`

Comment: any idea on how can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested previously it is likely that you had duplicate ID attributes within your HTML but as you were not using `document.getElementById` to address these elements Javascript would not have had cause for concern but it is still technically invalid markup. Using `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a live nodelist [see here for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) so each element in this collection needs to be treated individually if you are to assign an event listener to each one. ( An alternative approach is to assign a delegated event listener to a higher level parent element and inspect all click events )

The code below uses `document.querySelectorAll` which behaves in a similar manner to `getElementsByClassName`  and returns a nodelist through which you can iterate and assign the event handler. The `clickhandler` inspects the `event.target` to find which element invoked the `click` - from there it s possible to find the sibling element with class `.post-Menu` and modify the visibility therein.

```js
const clickhandler = (e) => {
  let el = e.target == e.currentTarget ? e.target : e.target.closest('div');
  el.parentNode.querySelector('.post-Menu').classList.toggle("postmenShow");
};

document.querySelectorAll('div.morebtn').forEach(bttn => bttn.addEventListener('click', clickhandler));
```

```css
svg {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  fill: red;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.post-Menu {
  display: none;
}

.postmenShow {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="postmenu">
  <div class="morebtn">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1hdv0qi">
            <g>
                <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
            </g>
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="post-Menu">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-pen"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="postmenu">
  <div class="morebtn">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1hdv0qi">
            <g>
                <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
            </g>
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="post-Menu">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-pen"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

An alternative approach using a delegated event listener rather than assigning the clickhandler to each element.

```js
// utility to try to find parent element in the dom
const getparent=(e,expr)=>{
    let n=e.target;
    do{
        if( Element.prototype.matches.call( n, expr ) ) return n;       
        n=n.previousElementSibling;
    }while( n!==null && n.nodeType===1 );
    
    
    n=e.target;
    do{
        if ( Element.prototype.matches.call( n, expr ) ) return n;
        n=n.parentNode;
    }while( n!==null && n.nodeType===1 );
    return n;
};

const delegatedclickhandler=(e) => {
  if (e.target != e.currrentTarget) {
    let el=getparent(e,'div.postmenu');
    el.querySelector('.post-Menu').classList.toggle("postmenShow");
  }
};

document.body.addEventListener('click', delegatedclickhandler);
```

```css
svg {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  fill: red;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.post-Menu {
  display: none;
}

.postmenShow {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="postmenu">
  <div class="morebtn">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1hdv0qi">
                <g>
                    <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                    <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                </g>
            </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="post-Menu">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-pen"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="postmenu">
  <div class="morebtn">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1hdv0qi">
                <g>
                    <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                    <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
                </g>
            </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="post-Menu">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-pen"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess the exact structure of your HTML, but it could be something like this. I added a `#wrapper` element and have the event listener on that. To get the right `.norebtn` I use [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) – so the `.morebtn` that is closest to the child element that was clicked get selected. In this example I just change the class name on the `.morebtn` adding `.on` and then use the [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators) `+` to style the following `.post-Menu` from the `.morebtn`.

```js
let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let morebtn = e.target.closest('.morebtn');
  if(morebtn){
    morebtn.classList.toggle("on");
  }
});
```

```css
.post-Menu {
  display: none;
}

.morebtn {
  width: 50px;
}

.morebtn.on {
  fill: red;
}

.morebtn.on+.post-Menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="postmenu">
    <div class="morebtn">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-1hdv0qi">
        <g>
          <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
          <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="2"></circle>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="post-Menu">
      <a href="">
        <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <div class="mlist"><i class="uil uil-pen"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```